# Table-overlapping Database Context in Entity Framework 6 Code First

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

Is there a possibility to create a table overlapping database context to avoid putting the database context in a library or creating different table prefixes/different databases for the same things?

To elaborate, this is an example of a CRM system.

### Database

```
- Pages
- Categories
- BlogEntries
- Comments
- Products
- Profiles
- Licenses
- Activations
- Invoices
- Customers
```

### DB Contexts

*Activation Server Context* uses

```
- Products
- Licenses
- Activations
- Customers
```

*Customer Relationship Context* uses

```
- Products
- Customers
- Invoices
```

*Frontend Website Context* uses

```
- Products
- Customers
- Invoices
- Profiles
- Pages
- Categories
- BlogEntries
- Comments
```

### Solutions

The only ways I could think of doing this...

- Creating one library with one db context that addresses all tables (incl. migrations etc.) -> Separation of concern?
- Splitting up related tables into different contexts with prefixes/database split -> Related table entries are not "tied together" (and I have to use guids to avoid duplicates, also using multiple contexts in one project)

Comment: What's the problem with defining a different context for each application domain? Why do you need prefixes/database split (I don't know what the latter means)? What do you mena by "Related entries are not tied together"?

Answer (score 1):

This is the primary reason I've avoided Domain Driven Design is because of questions like this.

I'd just have one big context... it's a repository wrapper and your repository is what it is. If you store everything in one big DB, then your context/repository should be one big repository, IMO.

It's not a separation of concern issue, in my opinion. in the sense that the context wraps repository concerns only, not business logic around those entities... it does one thing: Serialize and Deserialize data/entities from permanent storage.

We experimented about 4 years ago with domain driven design and we found that we were repeatedly having these fairly meaningless debates about 'does product belong in Domain 1 or Domain 2'. This is a real drag on productivity and it's really because DDD doesn't really fit most real world scenarios because overlap is the norm not the exception.